# Desplay a dialog message when no data in a list view android

Tags: android, list, view, dialog

I am developing an app to display some data which I receive from the web service. I used a custom adapter class for the list view which is extended from BaseAdapter class. I want to show a dialog box when there is no data in the list view. I tried with the help of getCount method which is inside my adapter class but it didnt work. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

This is my adapter class

```
public class NewsRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

static Dialog dialogs;
private static final String STIME = "StartTime";
private static final String END = "EndTime";
private static final String DATE = "Date";
private Context mContext;
private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
int resource;
    //String response;
    //Context context;
    //Initialize adapter
    public NewsRowAdapter(Context ctx,Activity act, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super();
        this.resource=resource;
        this.data = d;
        this.activity = act;
        this.mContext = ctx;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public void showFirstDialog(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("You Have Similar Kind of Appoinments!! Do you wanna Show them ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Showing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialogpop(list);


                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }

    public void dialogshow(final String Date,final String Start,final String End){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm your Action!");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes Confirm!!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    //MainActivity.this.finish();

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Yes clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //check similer records






                    //if duplicates > 1 then show the popup list
                    //if(duplicateList.size()>1){

                        /*final Dialog dialogs = new Dialog(activity);
                        dialogs.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list);
                        dialogs.setTitle("Select One");

                        ListView listView = (ListView) dialogs.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);
                        NewsRowAdapter nw = new NewsRowAdapter(mContext, activity, R.layout.dialog_row, duplicateList);
                        listView.setAdapter(nw);

                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialogs.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        dialogs.show();*/




                //  }





                }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }





    public void showDuplicateDialog(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        //CharSequence[] cs = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater infl = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = infl.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

        //NewsRowAdapter nw = new NewsRowAdapter(mContext, activity, R.layout.dialog_row, list);

        SimpleAdapter sim = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list, R.layout.dialog_row,  new String[] { STIME,END, DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.stime2,R.id.etime2, R.id.blank2});
        lv.setAdapter(sim);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Names);*/

        alertDialogBuilder2.setView(view)
        /*alertDialogBuilder2.setAdapter(sim, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
        */


        .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder2.show();
    }



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);


        final TextView firstname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.fname);
        final TextView lastname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lname);
        final TextView startTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.stime);
        final TextView endTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etime);
        final TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.blank);
        final TextView hidID = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.hidenID);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song =data.get(position);

        firstname.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_PROP_FNAME));
        lastname.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_PROP_LNAME));
        startTime.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_STIME));
        endTime.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ETIME));
        date.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DATE));
        hidID.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_HID));

        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), img);

        Button accept = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAccepted);
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int x = (int) getItemId(position);
                /*Intent zoom=new Intent(mContext, Profile.class);
                zoom.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                zoom.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(zoom);*/

                // get the intent from the hashmap check if there is similar date and time.
                //then store them in a list or array.

                String getDate = (String) date.getText();
                String getStartTime = startTime.getText().toString();
                String getEndTime = endTime.getText().toString();


                ShortList sh = new ShortList();

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> duplicateList; 
                duplicateList=sh.getDuplicated(getDate, getStartTime, getEndTime);

                if(duplicateList.size()>1){
                    //dialogshow(getDate,getStartTime,getEndTime);
                    showFirstDialog(duplicateList);
                }
                else{
                    dialogshow(getDate, getStartTime, getEndTime);

                }




            }
    });


        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String getPname = hidID.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: "+getPname , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //get the id of the view
                //check the id of the request
                //call the web service acording to the id





                Intent zoom=new Intent(parent.getContext(), Profile.class);  
                zoom.putExtra("PatientID", getPname);
                parent.getContext().startActivity(zoom);



            }
        });

        return vi;


}

public void dialogpop(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){

    dialogs = new Dialog(activity);
    dialogs.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list);
    dialogs.setTitle("Select One");



    ListView listView = (ListView) dialogs.findViewById(R.id.dialogList);

    //SimpleAdapter sim = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list, R.layout.dialog_row,  new String[] { STIME,END, DATE }, new int[] {
    //        R.id.stime2,R.id.etime2, R.id.blank2});

    Adapter_For_Dialog nw = new Adapter_For_Dialog(mContext,activity, R.layout.dialog_row, list);
    listView.setAdapter(nw);



    dialogs.show();

}





@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return data.size();

}



@Override
public Object getItem(int possision) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return possision;
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int possision) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return possision;
}
}
```

and in my main activity i check the response is empty or not also

this is my main activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
EditText userName;
EditText passWord;
ListView list;
TextView fname;
TextView lname;
TextView stime;
TextView etime;
TextView date;
ImageButton login;

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;  

//URL to get JSON Array
//private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";
private static String url ="my url is here";


public static  String confirm;
String firstName;

//JSON Node Names
 /*static final String TAG_OS = "android";
 static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
 static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 static final String TAG_API = "api";*/


static final String TAG_DATA = "d";
static final String TAG_OBJ_1 = "Appointment";
static final String TAG_OBJ_2 = "PatientProfile";
static final String TAG_PROP_FNAME = "FirstName";
static final String TAG_PROP_LNAME = "LastName";
static final String TAG_STIME = "StartTime";
static final String TAG_ETIME = "EndTime";
static final String TAG_DATE = "Date";
static final String TAG_HID = "PatientPersonId";



//static final String TAG_API = "NickName";
JSONArray androids = null;
JSONObject duplicate;
```

public static JSONArray dupArray;

```
public JSONArray getJsonArray() {
    return dupArray;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loging);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)

    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    }



    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    login = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();







    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public
        void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //if login success then call below 
            userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
            passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassWord);

            String name = userName.getText().toString().trim();
            String passwd = passWord.getText().toString().trim();

            CheckLogin check = new CheckLogin();
            confirm = check.AuthenticateUser(name, passwd);



            if(!(confirm.equals("-1"))){
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Check Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
}





public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       fname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fname);
       lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lname);
       stime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stime);
       etime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etime);
       date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blank);
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.setCancelable(true);
       pDialog.show();

   }


   @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

       // Getting JSON from URL
       JSONObject json = null;
    try {

        JSONObject parm = new JSONObject();
        //parm.put("PersonID", confirm);
        parm.put("caregiverPersonId", confirm);
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(parm,url);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi "+firstName+"You Don't Have Any Requests!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
       return json;
}


   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       pDialog.dismiss();
       try {
              // Getting JSON Array from URL
           //JSONObject jobs  = json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);

           String emptyjson = json.getString(TAG_DATA);

           if(emptyjson.equals("[]")){



               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Empty.class));
           }
           else
           {

           androids = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);


            //JSONObject appt= new JSONObject(json.getString("d"));


           for(int i = 0; i < androids.length(); i++){
              JSONObject c = androids.getJSONObject(i);

              // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

              JSONObject job  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_2);

              firstName = job.getString(TAG_PROP_FNAME);
              String lastName = job.getString(TAG_PROP_LNAME);

              JSONObject job_two  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1).getJSONObject("DayTimeSlot");

              String start = job_two.getString(TAG_STIME );
              String end = job_two.getString(TAG_ETIME);


            /*  String ackwardDate = job_two.getString(TAG_DATE);;
              Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
              Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
              calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
              String theDate = (calendar.getTime().toGMTString());
              */
              String Ldate = job_two.getString(TAG_DATE);
              String ackwardRipOff = Ldate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
              Long Ldat = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
              Date date = new Date(Ldat);
              String strdate = (String) DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy", date);


              JSONObject toHid = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1);

              String Hid = toHid.getString(TAG_HID);

              //String date = dateConvert(Ldate);
              //long Ldate = job_two.getLong("Date");


              //String strdate = (String) DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy h:mmaa", date);

              // Adding value HashMap key => value

              HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

              map.put(TAG_PROP_FNAME, firstName);
              map.put(TAG_PROP_LNAME, lastName);
              map.put(TAG_STIME , start);
              map.put(TAG_ETIME, end);
              map.put(TAG_DATE, strdate);
              map.put(TAG_HID, Hid);

              oslist.add(map);

              //duplicate = new JSONObject();

              Intent reult = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewList.class);
              //reult.putStringArrayListExtra("map", oslist);
              //startActivity(reult);


              reult.putExtra("arraylist", oslist);
              startActivityForResult(reult, 500);



              }


           dupArray = new JSONArray();
           dupArray.put(oslist);
           }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          //Intent reult = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewList.class);
          //reult.putStringArrayListExtra("map", oslist);
         // startActivity(reult);



      }


   }
}


    public String dateConvert(String d){

        Date dt = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String strDate = df.format(dt);


        return strDate;


    }


}
```

here my View List class which is the activity when the data is there

```
public class ViewList extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_API = "api";

    ListView list;
    NewsRowAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empty;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");

        list  =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);       

        adapter  = new NewsRowAdapter(getBaseContext(),ViewList.this, R.layout.row, arl);    
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
       // setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finishAffinity();
    startActivity(new Intent(ViewList.this,MainActivity.class));

}
}
```

Comment: Make your adapter global..

Comment: inside `ViewList` if(arl.size()<=0) then display dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Change code in ViewList like below:

```
list  =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

adapter  = new NewsRowAdapter(getBaseContext(),ViewList.this, R.layout.row, arl);

if(adapter.getCount()!=0){
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
else{
   your dialog message
}
```

Comment: i got Null Pointer Exeption :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of the `length()` attribute available for `JSONArray`. If the length of the array is greater than 0 you proceed with retrieving the remaining values from it else you can display the dialog over there.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       pDialog.dismiss();
       try {
              // Getting JSON Array from URL
           //JSONObject jobs  = json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);

            androids = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

           if(androids.length() > 0){



               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Empty.class));
           }
           else
           {


            //JSONObject appt= new JSONObject(json.getString("d"));


           for(int i = 0; i < androids.length(); i++){
              JSONObject c = androids.getJSONObject(i);

              // Storing  JSON item in a Variable

              JSONObject job  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_2);

              firstName = job.getString(TAG_PROP_FNAME);
              String lastName = job.getString(TAG_PROP_LNAME);

              JSONObject job_two  = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1).getJSONObject("DayTimeSlot");

              String start = job_two.getString(TAG_STIME );
              String end = job_two.getString(TAG_ETIME);


            /*  String ackwardDate = job_two.getString(TAG_DATE);;
              Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
              Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
              calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
              String theDate = (calendar.getTime().toGMTString());
              */
              String Ldate = job_two.getString(TAG_DATE);
              String ackwardRipOff = Ldate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
              Long Ldat = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
              Date date = new Date(Ldat);
              String strdate = (String) DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy", date);


              JSONObject toHid = c.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_1);

              String Hid = toHid.getString(TAG_HID);

              //String date = dateConvert(Ldate);
              //long Ldate = job_two.getLong("Date");


              //String strdate = (String) DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy h:mmaa", date);

              // Adding value HashMap key => value

              HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

              map.put(TAG_PROP_FNAME, firstName);
              map.put(TAG_PROP_LNAME, lastName);
              map.put(TAG_STIME , start);
              map.put(TAG_ETIME, end);
              map.put(TAG_DATE, strdate);
              map.put(TAG_HID, Hid);

              oslist.add(map);

              //duplicate = new JSONObject();

              Intent reult = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewList.class);
              //reult.putStringArrayListExtra("map", oslist);
              //startActivity(reult);


              reult.putExtra("arraylist", oslist);
              startActivityForResult(reult, 500);



              }


           dupArray = new JSONArray();
           dupArray.put(oslist);
           }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          //Intent reult = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewList.class);
          //reult.putStringArrayListExtra("map", oslist);
         // startActivity(reult);



      }
```